# Accessing Chrome Browser Passwords (Read+Write) from an Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access the Chrome stored passwords via a Chrome extension?

We want to create secure a team-password sharing plugin, and it would be cool to not need to rewrite the form-filling code and so on.

Answer (score 6):

No there is no way to access Chrome stored passwords via a Chrome extension, you only can delete them using chrome [browsingData API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData).

Maybe what you are looking for is [Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api), Unfortunately there is no way currently that extension can register itself as a credential manager, there is also [bug filed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707900) regarding that.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is not possible. If any extension could access the password store, that would be a security problem.

I would advice to create your own password store. Make sure to protect it sufficiently.

Comment: There is a permission management for Extensions I think? So when installing, there could be a prompt. But you might be right :)

Comment: This is correct, [there is no API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) to access password storage. Also, securing a password store from JavaScript is nigh-impossible, considering the very convenient debugger built into Chrome.

Comment: @Alex Maybe you can use a plugin to secure your passwords.

Comment: I don't have the problem, if the user can access the passwords via dev tools. He knows them anyways and it is not possible to store them on the their computer without the chance to extract them, if the passphrase is known.

Comment: @PiTheNumber How would it be a security problem? And what does this have to do with plugins?

Comment: @DanielHerr Well, if every simple browser extension could steal all passwords. That would be bad, right? In Chrome, Plugins are external programs. They use a different API to interact with Chrome.

Comment: @PiTheNumber Why would every extension be able to do that? There would be a permission warning.